# Colocar texto arriba a la izquierda después de usar la propiedad table-layout: fixed; en CSS

Tags: html, css

Estoy generando una tabla en HTML, necesito que una columna en concreto tenga una longitud fija, lo logre usando la propiedad `table-layout: fixed;`
en HTML esta de la siguiente manera:

```
<th id="contenido" colspan="3">Contenido </th>
```

Con las propiedades CSS:

```
#contenido {
    table-layout: fixed;
    text-align: left;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
}
```

Mi resultado fue el siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo, de desearía que el texto se alineara de la siguiente manera:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero no quiero perder la propiedad `table-layout: fixed;` ya que es necesario tener una longitud fija en la tabla

De antemano muchas gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que hice fue agregar **`display: flex;`** y luego alinear al contenido con **`align-items: start;`** para que esté alineado tu texto arriba, te muestro un ejemplo con la etiqueta **`<div>`** para que se observe mejor los resultados:

```css
#contenido {
    table-layout: fixed;
    text-align: left;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    overflow: auto; /*evitamos que el texto se salga del div*/
    display: flex; /*agregamos la propiedad flex*/
    align-items: start; /*alineamos el contenido arriba*/
    border: 1px solid black; /*le damos un borde para observar los cambios*/
}
```

```html
<div id="contenido" colspan="3">Contenido</div>
```

Integrando el código en una tabla, quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```css
th{
  padding: 0 !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
}

#contenido {
    table-layout: fixed;
    text-align: left;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    overflow: auto; /*evitamos que el texto se salga del div*/
    display: flex; /*agregamos la propiedad flex*/
    align-items: start; /*alineamos el contenido arriba*/
    border: 3px solid black; /*le damos un borde para observar los cambios*/
}
```

```html
<table>
  <th colspan="3"><div id="contenido">Contenido</div> </th>
  <th colspan="3"><div id="contenido">Contenido</div> </th>
  <th colspan="3"><div id="contenido">Contenido</div> </th>
</table>
```

Comment: Hola si alineo las letras sin embargo mi espacios de tabla se puso uno debajo del otro, edito mi respuesta y hasta abajo coloco de imagen de como se alinearon

Comment: Edité mi respuesta, sería encerrar el texto en un div y a ese div darle las propiedades, de esta forma no afectaría a las demás cabeceras de las columnas.

Comment: Muchas gracias, quise dejarlo para hoy porque ayer estaba super desesperado, muchas gracias